# How to print out lifetime parameters

Tags: rust, lifetime

Is there a way to print out the lifetime parameters generated by the Rust compiler? I find it helpful for learning Rust's lifetime rules by examining the output of the rustc compiler to examine the claims of various books and articles.

For instance, given the following code:

```
fn f(r: &i32, s: &i32) -> i32 {...}
```

Can I see the lifetime used by Rust is something like below?

```
fn f<'a, 'b>(r: &'a i32, s: &'b i32) -> &'a i32 {...}
```

Comment: Usually you don't need to see the lifetime parameters of functions anyway. The [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) are very common sense, and if your function doesn't match them you have to explicitly provide the lifetimes yourself.

Comment: @cdhowie This is for my learning purpose. I'd like to see output of compiler from time to time to confirm if I understand what an author says.

Comment: Thanks, @kmdreko. I used the example because on P121 of the book _Programming Rust 2ed_ , the author says "Rust just assigns a distinct lifetime to each spot that needs one", and then gives the example that starts with `struct S<'a, 'b>`. It's a surprise to me, hence I wanted to see what Rust actually does. I updated example per your comment anyway.